# Why I am getting this compile error in c++/clr

Tags: compiler-errors, c++-cli

I have this code:

```
public ref class NativeDll
{
    DllInterface *dllInterface;
public:
    NativeDll(String ^dllName)
    {
        msclr::interop::marshal_context context;
        std::string stdDllName = context.marshal_as<std::string>(dllName);

        dllInterface=new DllInterface(stdDllName);
    }
    NativeDll()
    {
        auto assembly= Assembly::GetExecutingAssembly();
        String ^path=Path::GetDirectoryName(assembly->FullName);
        auto pathName=Path::Combine(path,"MyDLL.dll");
        NativeDll(pathName);
    }
};
```

When I compile it, I am getting tis error:

```
'pathName' : redefinition; different type modifiers
```

It generate this error on line:

```
  NativeDll(pathName);
```

Changing pathname to anything would generate the same error. Why I am getting this error?

Comment: Please change your tag from [c++] to [c++-cli] or something else.

Answer (score 0):

In C++ you cannot call a constructor from another constructor. Nor in C++/Cli AFAIK. Make a method that both constructors call instead:

```
NativeDll(String ^dllName)
{
    initialize(dllName);
}

NativeDll()
{
    auto assembly= Assembly::GetExecutingAssembly();
    String ^path=Path::GetDirectoryName(assembly->FullName);
    auto pathName=Path::Combine(path,"MyDLL.dll");

    initialize(dllName);
}

void initialize(String ^dllName)
{
    msclr::interop::marshal_context context;
    std::string stdDllName = context.marshal_as<std::string>(dllName);

    dllInterface=new DllInterface(stdDllName);
}
```